# stream.addLike api facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

i have trouble in my facebook apps when im using facebook api stream.addLike to my status automatically..

`https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.addLike?uid=MY FB ID&post_id=MY FB ID_STREAM ID&access_token=MY FRIEND ACCESS TOKEN CODE`

with permissions of

`user_online_presence,friends_online_presence,offline_access,user_activities,friends_activities,user_likes,friends_likes,friends_notes,friends_photos,user_status,friends_status,read_stream,publish_stream,read_friendlists,read_mailbox,read_requests,xmpp_login`

i try it lately the error is "Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user."

error code 240

anyone has know about this? please help . :) sorry for my lame english.. :)

Answer (score -1):

You are using an API that is deprecated.  Please upgrade your code to use one of the APIs currently supported.

Comment: No, it is deprecated.  It is no longer supported and will be turned off soon. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.addLike/